# C# WinForms Combobox.DropDownStyle sometimes causing an exception when changed

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a form that uses 2 combo boxes to select a job and an SQL query to edit/create. If the combo box is at index 0, I set the DropDownStyle to DropDownStyle.DropDown so the user can edit the text. When they press enter, it will create a new job or query depending on which combo box they used and add it to the respective box. If the boxes are at any other index, I set the DropDownStyle to DropDownStyle.DropDownList so the text isn't editable.

Sometimes, when changing the DropDownStyle, a System.AccessViolationException is thrown:

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6hSP.png)

I've wrapped the code that changes the DropDownStyle in try-catch blocks and put break points in the catch blocks, but it doesn't break at those points and instead breaks at the call that shows the form.
Here's the 2 methods in the form that changes the DropDownStyle:

```
        private void CboJob_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                cboJob.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            txtSQL.TextChanged -= TxtSQL_TextChanged;
            txtSQL.Text = "";
            txtSQL.Enabled = false;
            txtSQL.TextChanged += TxtSQL_TextChanged;
            cboQuery.Items.Clear();
            if (cboJob.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                cboQuery.Enabled = true;
                btnDeleteJob.Enabled = true;
                cboQuery.Items.Add("<New Query>");
                cboQuery.Items.AddRange(_jobs[cboJob.SelectedIndex - 1].Queries.ToArray());
                if (cboQuery.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    cboQuery.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    cboQuery.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cboQuery.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (cboJob.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    cboJob.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

```
        private void CboQuery_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                cboQuery.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            if (cboQuery.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                if (_jobs[cboJob.SelectedIndex - 1].Queries.Count > 0)
                {
                    txtSQL.Enabled = true;
                    btnDeleteQuery.Enabled = true;
                    txtSQL.Text = _jobs[cboJob.SelectedIndex - 1].Queries[cboQuery.SelectedIndex - 1].Sql;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnDeleteQuery.Enabled = false;
                    txtSQL.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnDeleteQuery.Enabled = false;
                txtSQL.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (cboQuery.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    cboQuery.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the method that shows the form:

```
        private void BtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var frmSQL = new EditSQLForm();

            try
            {
                if (frmSQL.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)//this is the line it breaks at
                {
                    _jobs = frmSQL.Jobs;
                    Save();
                    GetData();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            frmSQL.Dispose();
        }
```

I think the reason why the try-catch blocks aren't catching it is because the code that's throwing the exception is a Windows DLL called "comctl32.dll". If I turn on native code debugging, I get this exception:

[native code exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wePkA.png)

I've looked all over the place for information about this and couldn't find anything useful. I've run a memory test on the computer and it came out ok. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: When you set the `DropDownStyle` of a ComboBox, the handle of the control is recreated. Its previous handle is no longer valid.

Comment: I was having the same issue, and I solved it by using the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead of `SelectedIndexChanged`. The former only fires if the user changes the selection, whereas the later is also fired if `SelectedIndex` is changed programmatically, so you may need to handle those cases separately.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance there is a problem in the line

```
if (_jobs[cboJob.SelectedIndex - 1].Queries.Count > 0)
```

When `cboJob.SelectedIndex` is 0 the exception will be thrown here. Try to add an additional condition (below is your code + my comment in the modified line):

```
        private void CboQuery_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                cboQuery.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            if (cboQuery.SelectedIndex > 0 && cboJob.SelectedIndex > 0) // ADDITIONAL CONDITION!
            {
                if (_jobs[cboJob.SelectedIndex - 1].Queries.Count > 0)
                {
                    txtSQL.Enabled = true;
                    btnDeleteQuery.Enabled = true;
                    txtSQL.Text = _jobs[cboJob.SelectedIndex - 1].Queries[cboQuery.SelectedIndex - 1].Sql;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnDeleteQuery.Enabled = false;
                    txtSQL.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnDeleteQuery.Enabled = false;
                txtSQL.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (cboQuery.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    cboQuery.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

This should help to avoid negative indexing in the code.